# How can we clearly state in our title that the question is always open to new answers?

Tags: discussion

Everyone will be influenced by a question's answer number. When there's already an answer to a question, people will hesitate to answer it.

But sometimes we need multiple solutions to a questions, the more the better; or sometimes we need multiple ideas and approach to a question.

Usually people won't see the poster's need simply by viewing the title of the question and simply pass it as there's already an solution.

So my problem is: How to solve this and make clear in our title that this question is always open to new answers?

Comment: This certainly is not a problem with [tag:list-manipulation] questions. :D Nevertheless, thanks for raising this; altho I feel that the regulars will always contribute good ideas whether or not there are previous answers, my concern is with the less active, who might be a bit more timid.

Comment: It will always be a concern for those who want to gain reputation to show their contribution~(Partially including myself as I won't touch a question if there's already an answer unless it's truely my expertise or I find it extremely amusing or I suddenly have a flow of thought coming though me while viewing its title :P .)

Comment: If you genuinely, really, truly believe that you have something to share that hasn't been covered by other answers, and even if one of those answers has already been accepted, you should never let yourself be dissuaded from posting it. It can happen that your approach will turn out to be more elegant/efficient/whatever than the extant solutions.

Comment: I've brought this up in the past - there are questions with accepted answers where another later answer is clearly superior (in some cases the accepted answer is even *wrong*), suggested a group of vetted participants have the ability to flag as such and draw attention to such improved answers.

Comment: I don't think the number of previous answers stops frequent  answer writers like me from wading in. When an answer occurs to me that no one has already posted, and I think it would be useful or just interesting or amusing, the only thing that stops me from posting is the question being already closed.

Comment: It's widely known that late answers gains much less attention and that's why I think we need some kind of symbol clearly to ensure the answerers that their efforts will pays off.

Comment: Although I have a number of "Revival" and "Necromancer" badges, I do agree that sometimes late answers do not get as much attention as earlier ones. But none of us is really in a position to force people to look at late answers.